# Unable to install ubuntu, computer restarts

Tags: boot, asus

I’m on a ASUS GL752VW laptop trying to dual-boot ubuntu 16.04 with my windows 10 installed in LEGACY bios with a burned DVD.
When I get to the (legacy) installer whatever the option I choose in the installer my computer just goes black screen for several seconds then restart.
PS: I tried the acpi=off and it didn't solve my problem neither did my attempt to make another DVD.